# How to check undefined items in a pipe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I use Angular2 with a custom pipe to filter my items like:

```
transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
   if (args) {
         return value.filter(foo => foo.url.indexOf(args) != -1)
   };
   return value;
}
```

but some of my `foo.url` items are undefined and I got this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

How can I check if the property is undefined and will be filtered?

Comment: You mean besides using `if (!foo.url)`? Also, please read the descriptions of the tags you add to your question. Both [tag:filter] and [tag:pipe] have nothing to do with Angular or JavaScript.

Comment: sorry, I fixed that...

Comment: @mike-mccaughan besides that can you show me the syntax in my filter function?

Comment: this is something that's going to come up a lot in your development, and I really think you should try some things out first. If I just spoon-feed you the answer, you won't learn anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
  if (args) {
     return value.filter(foo => {
       return (foo.url && (foo.url.indexOf(args) != -1));
     });
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **TypeScript**, so it's time to start taking advantage of all the benefits that come with it. Instead of writing this `transform` function with a parameter of type `any`, specify the type. This will help to alleviate silly runtime issues like this. You are clearly assuming that the `value` parameter is an array, so declare it as one (we'll do the same for the return type). Then what type of array it is, let's demonstrate this...instead of:

```
transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
   if (args) {
         return value.filter(foo => foo.url.indexOf(args) != -1)
   };
   return value;
}
```

Let's write it like this:

```
transform(value: Foo[], args: string[]): Foo[] {
   if (args) {
         return value.filter(foo => foo.url.indexOf(args) != -1)
   };
   return value;
}
```

Then we can have a class that represents `Foo`:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(url: string);
}
```

This will ensure help prevent runtime issues where the property `url` is `undefined` at runtime.